# In TCP Congestion Avoidance Phase, are cwnd and CongWin the same thing?

Tags: tcp, congestion

I'm trying to understand TCP Congestion Avoidance Phase.

According to pages 82-83 of the slide below, cwnd equals CongWin.

According to pages 84-85, they are different. The writer did not bother to define those terms.

Any idea what's going on?

http://cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~morhan/cs421/lectures/Chapter3_spring15.pdf

Comment: Don't cross-post on multiple SE sites. You already asked this question on SO. You should delete one or the other.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same thing.

> The writer did not bother to define those terms.

If you feel that way you should try to find the answer yourself. The first result you get when Googling "tcp cwnd" is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) Wikipedia page which states:

> Slow-start begins initially with a **cong**estion **wind**ow Size (**cwnd**) of 1,
>   2 or 10.

As I have highlighted in bold, conwind and cwnd both mean Congestion Window.

If you'd like to learn more about TCP/IP, I can't recommend [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_toc.htm) enough. It is an excellent book, and free too. If you do get good use out of it though I suggest you purchase a copy of it too as a "thank you" to the author.